# mounting a network drive cifs mac osx

Tags: macos, mount, cifs

I've been handed a mac and I'm having issues. I had an ubuntu setup where I would type:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //fs/CakeRecipes /mnt/fs/CakeRecipes -o username=fegur,domain=KitchenLord,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777
```

to get access to the CakeRecipes folder. Sadly this does not work on OSX. If I type in this command directly, I get

```
mount: exec /Library/Filesystems/cifs.fs/Contents/Resources/mount_cifs for /mnt/fs/KitchenLord: No such file or directory
```

I have created /mnt/fs/KitchenLord on my local machine, so I'm not sure what this error is talking about.

Any hints would be appreciated. Googling is not helping much.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On OS X, the filesystem plugin for CIFS/SMB is named smbfs, and its options are a bit different. I think it should be something like this:

```
sudo mount -t smbfs -o -f=0777,-d=0777 '//KitchenLord;fegur@fs/CakeRecipes' /mnt/fs/CakeRecipes
```

...but in my quick test it doesn't seem to be obeying the -`f` and `-d` options. Anyway, check the [man page for `mount_smbfs`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/mount_smbfs.8.html) for more info.

Comment: cifs and smbfs are not the same thing with a different name on macOS: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34742/cifs-vs-samba-what-are-the-differences

Answer (score 8):

To mount

```
mount_smbfs //username@server.name/share_name share_name/
```

To unmount

```
umount share_name
```